# Simple spring DI Query

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have 2 code blocks

1

```
Class Employee
{
Address address;
Employee()
{
address=new Address();
}
```

}

2

```
Class Employee
    {
    Address address;
    Employee(Address address)
    {
    this.address=address;
    }
}
```

Then,how come 2nd block is loosly coupled and 1st is tightly coupled and why 1st will be hard to test and maintain sa compared to second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first block is considered tightly coupled because the Employee class creates a new `Address` instance directly.  The second is considered loosely coupled because the `Address` instance is created somewhere outside the `Employee` class.  As RonU commented, one example of using loose coupling is to facilitate the use of mock objects for testing purposes:

```
Address mockAddress = mock(Address.class);

Employee test = new Employee(mockAddress);
```

Comment: And to elaborate on the testing question, the reason the second is easier to test is because your test can provide the Address object (which may be a subclass, mock, or other test fixture that gives you more control over how Address behaves).